# viewDidLayoutSubviews called after touchesBegan - again and again

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, touchesbegan

In [an iPhone word game](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/Scroll) I have an `UIScrollView` (holding `UIImageView`) and 7 draggable custom `UIView`s placed initially at the bottom (and outside the scroll view):

[image: app screenshot]

In the single [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/Scroll/Scroll/ViewController.m) I have overwritten `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so that it always sets the `zoomScale` of the scroll view - to have the `UIImageView` fill exactly 100% of the screen width.

This works well - for portrait and landscape modes. And when the app is just started:

[image: portrait]

[image: landscape]

**My problem** is however, when I first pinch/zoom/double-tap the scroll view and then move one of the seven [Tile.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/Scroll/Scroll/Tile.m) views:

Suddenly (not every time) `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called after `touchesBegan`.

This resets the zoom of the scroll view - unexpectedly for the user.

**My question** is if there is any way to disable this behavior?

Is it possible to prevent `viewDidLayoutSubviews` call of the parent, when its child `UIView` is being touched/dragged?

**UPDATE:**

I've moved the `zoomScale` setting code from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and the scroll view zoom is okay now, but its `contentOffset` is reset to `{0,0}`, when (not always) I drag a Tile - i.e. the scroll view jumps suddenly, the app is unusable.

Adding the following to `viewDidLoad` hasn't helped:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:)])
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called whenever the system performs layout on the view (`layoutSubviews`). This can be called for a plethora of reasons; you can subclass your view, implement an empty `layoutSubviews` method (don't forget to call the `super` implementation!) and put a breakpoint there to see who causes the layout. You may also want to implement `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`, and put breakpoints there also for your investigation, as these trigger layout on followup runloops.

But you will never be able to prevent layout. The system performs layout on many occasions which are outside of your control. For example, if a user makes a call, exists the phone app and returns to your app; a layout is triggered because the bounds and frame of the window have changed. The call ends; layout is again triggered because now the window is back to previous size.

You should be responsible for figuring out when to set the zoom scale. For example, if the user starts a gesture, you should signal your code not to perform changes, even if a layout was performed.

Comment: +1 thanks. I've moved the `zoomScale` setting code to `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and the scroll view zoom is okay now, but the `contentOffset` is reset to `{0,0}`, when (not always) I drag a Tile - i.e. the scroll view jumps suddenly, the app is unusable.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber subclass the scrollview and see who is setting it to {0,0}.  I've even gone as having to lock down my scrollview to ignore scrolls from unwanted system decisions. But you have to figure out who is doing it.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber So what was causing it?

Comment: I think what I'm trying for my game is not possible with Autolayout on. So I've switched it off and the scroll view doesn't jump anymore (the `contentOffset` does not reset). But I suddenly have other problems (the board image is stretched)... I will search/try more and prepare another question. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber If you have other questions, let me know.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber You can find my LinkedIn details on my page.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber OK, I will add you. You can remove the mail now so people don't spam you.