# UIScrollView doesn't scroll on iPad but works on iPhone

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

**UPDATE**

I know turning off `AutoLayout` fixes the scrolling issue.  However, I want to use `AutoLayout` still.  Why does it work on iPhone and not iPad?  Is there a work-around to this?  This seems like a bug...

---

I've tried several things to get this to work and nothing seems to do it for me.  I have a function that I call in `viewDidAppear` that resizes my UIScrollView's content size.  My view height is 916 and the log is saying it's resizing the content height to 1267.  Scrolling is enabled (I have it set in the storyboard but also set it in code to try to get this to work).

Here's the odd thing.  If I click inside of a text field, scrolling suddenly works.  I do alter the scroll view's content size during that time, but anything I do there I have tried doing within my resize function and it still did not work.  The resize function is below as well as the animation for when I click inside a text view.

```
- (void)resize_scrollview_to_fit {
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
        if (view.frame.size.height + view.frame.origin.y > scrollViewHeight) {
            scrollViewHeight = view.frame.size.height + view.frame.origin.y + 10;

            NSLog(@"Inside Scroll View 'If' Statement");
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Resizing scroll view to fit: %f", scrollViewHeight);

    [scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollViewHeight))];

    NSLog(@"Scrollview content height: %f", scrollView.contentSize.height);

    NSLog(@"Screen height: %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
}
```

The log I get for this each time it is ran is:

```
2014-06-26 14:14:05.455 eTicket[1113:60b] Inside Scroll View 'If' Statement
2014-06-26 14:14:05.456 eTicket[1113:60b] Resizing scroll view to fit: 1267.000000
2014-06-26 14:14:05.457 eTicket[1113:60b] Scrollview content height: 1267.000000
2014-06-26 14:14:05.458 eTicket[1113:60b] Screen height: 1024.000000
```

---

```
- (void) animateTextView:(UITextView *) textView up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = keyboardSize.height - 58; // tweak as needed
    //const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    NSLog(@"Moving View Up: %f", keyboardSize.height);

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height + movement);

    [self resize_scrollview_to_fit];

    if (up && textView.frame.origin.y + 10 < scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textView.frame.origin.y - 10);
    }else if (up) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }else{

    }
}
```

I have placed the `resize_scrollview_to_fit` method call in several places within the code with no change in functionality.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Have you tried putting it int `viewDidLayoutSubviews` ?

Comment: Do you having bouncing enabled?  If so does it bounce and just not scroll?  Scroll views won't always scroll if their content size isn't setup right.

Comment: @InkGolem Yes, bouncing is on and it is not bouncing.  Also, the NSLog shows that the content height is correctly set after I set it.  And if I turn off auto layout it works just fine.  Very odd.

Comment: @Losiowaty I did not, but would it matter?  It is already getting the correct content size and applying it successfully (or so the NSLogs show), it just doesn't scroll.  The oddest part is that everything works if I turn off auto layout.

Comment: Well I had similar issues (diasbling autolayout also helped) and moving the part where i set `contentSize` to `viewDidLayouSubviews` helped. Actually, I learned that this was the first method where you could be sure that autolayout wouldn't change anything from his moment forward.

Comment: @Losiowaty I'll have to try that when I get back to work tomorrow.  I dislike the fact that I have to turn off auto layout to set these properties myself.  In my opinion, we should be able to overwrite them after the view loads.

Comment: @James : refer to the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237271/viewdidlayoutsubviews-called-after-touchesbegan-again-and-again

Comment: @Losiowaty Finally had a chance to try this.  This appears to be what I needed.  using `viewDidLayouSubviews` does allow me to set the content size and have it affect the view laid out on iPad.  Thank you.  Can you make that an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comments under the question :

When using AutoLayout, you should set `contentSize` of UIScrollView in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` - after that method you can be fairly sure that autolayout won't change anything. Refer to [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22237422/765298) for some more explanation about `viewDidLayoutSubviews`